# Jquery append is not working for dynamic display

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

> I am working on a E-commerce webapp. I have stored items in a cart object in localStorage. I am trying to **dynamically display item list in cart in an 'ul' tag of html using jquery append method**. But it is showing the whole html (mystr) as string only in the browser. Below the HTML part for "ul" tag:

```
        <div class="my-3">
            <ul class="list-group" id="items">
                <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    Cras justo odio
                    <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">14</span>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    Dapibus ac facilisis in
                    <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">2</span>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    Morbi leo risus
                    <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">1</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

> Below is the javascript code for dynamic displaying of cart items stored in localStorage:

```
    for( var item in cart){
       var qty = cart[item][0];
       var name = cart[item][1];
       mystr = `li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    $(name)
                    <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">$(qty)</span>
                </li> ` ;

       $('#items').append(mystr);
    }
```

> please if anybody have any idea, do respond to it.

Comment: The opening bracket of the <li> is missing in the definition of mystr, it should be mystr = `<li

Answer (score 0):

The opening bracket of the li is missing along with that use ${name} and ${qty} instead of  $(name) and $(qty)

for more information visit [multiline-strings-in-es6-javascript](https://jack.ofspades.com/multiline-strings-in-es6-javascript/)